# How can I pevent creating shortcut more than one time?

Tags: android, shortcut, homescreen

I have written the following code for creating a shortcut of my application in Home screen:

```
private void createShortcut() {

        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(this, ActActivation.class);
        shortcutIntent.setClassName("org.mabna.order",
                "org.mabna.order.ui.ActActivation");
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "test");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon));
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        this.sendBroadcast(addIntent);

    }
```

It works correctly but every time I run my program and this code is run, I get the message "Shortcut Test created" and a new shortcut is added to my home screen. After 10 time opening my application, I have 10 shortcut.

How can I prevent this message box and creating multiple shortcuts?

Comment: Set a `boolean` in `SharePreferences` and check at every run. Toggle to `true` on the first run. Simplest thing I can think of.

Comment: @IceMAN If user clears application data, the shortcut is created again

Comment: @breceivemail look at my answer , i was facing sample problem but i have solved this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Create `SharedPrefernce` as well as add this Line , you dont need any other permission for Uninstallation

```
addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
```

**Code After Changes**

```
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(this, ActActivation.class);
    shortcutIntent.setClassName("org.mabna.order",
            "org.mabna.order.ui.ActActivation");
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "test");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon));
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false); // Just create once
    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    this.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

This will create only single icon on HomeScreen , if user clear `Cache` this will prevent app from creating another Icon on Homescreen.

**EDIT :** Code is tested in android 4.2(JellyBean) where it is working fine.

Comment: `addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);` doesn't work on devices above API 14.

Comment: Thanks! Good solution. How can I prevent that message?

Comment: @Rstar I have tested and it is OK. But I have noticed that it does not work on some new APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no API help in preventing duplicates. There's no API for seeing what's on the home screen either (at least not without hacking the launcher data). The best you can do is to track whether you've already created a short-cut or not. That's easiest to do with a shared preference. See the [storage options guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

It's better to go this way anyway. If you always creat a shortcut if it doesn't currently exist, you'll quickly alienate any user that has manually deleted your shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use `SharedPreferences`:

```
private static final String SHORTCUT = "SHORTCUT";
//...
if (!preferences.readBool(SHORTCUT, false)) {
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SomeActivity.class);

    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                    Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.drawable.app_icon));
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);

    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);

    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
    edit.putBoolean(SHORTCUT, true);
    edit.apply();
}
```

---

But, if user clear App Data and start App again, **duplicate will be created**.

Comment: if you delete cache you will get duplicated :)

Comment: and the others app. how do they do that ?